# How do i handle dynamic text height in a cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UILabel inside a UITableViewCell. I am not using autolayout, but creating and adding the views manually. 
The UILabel can contain a variable amount of text so in my tableview delegate i implement heightForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   TableCellWithDocument *cell = (TableCellWithDocument*)[self tableView: tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
   NSLog(@"Cell frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
   return [cell heightForCellForWidth: cell.frame.size.width];
```

The problem i'm having is that when this delegate method is called, the frame size of the cell is not correct. It just returns "default" 320x44.
So when i try to calculate the label size, i have the wrong cell width and my cell height gets the wrong height.

In my subclassed TableCellWithDocument class, i can override layoutSubviews and get the correct cell width, but that is too late since heightForRowAtIndexPath has already been called.

How should i handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in recursive manner. If you carefully debug your code, you will find that `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called first to estimate cell height, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called later.

Ideally, within `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, you should take all your data source content, and estimate the size of it. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should be able to use this height to set the cell content.

For example, if there is some text to be displayed, you could use `[UILabel sizeThatFits]` or `[NSString sizeWithFont]` method to estimate `cell.textLabel` size, and so on.

Remember that no answer is the right answer and you must do tweaks according your own data - be it strings, images or anything else. It's data size, not the size of your controls - that must decide what you return from `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in Your heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"YourFont" size:24.0];
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(kMessageTextWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                       lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


    return MAX(size.height + 17.0f);
}
```

Comment: sizeWithFont method is deprecated for iOS7.0 onward. You will need to use boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context: method instead.